# Calculate Number of Consecutive Substring in a String using Perl

Tags: perl

I have a string with multiple sequences of consecutive String like:

my $substring = "CAG";
my $str = "CAGCAGCAGCAGPGHSMCAGCAG";

I want to calculate the max repeated substring in the str.

Comment: Did you try anything? If so, edit the question and add what you have tried and the errors you got.

Comment: @Valentino I know that is not useful to get algorithms from stackoverflow and i don't ask for that i know how to solve the problem with loops but i just want to know if there an effective solution with regex

Comment: Have you taken a look at the transliteration operator (`tr///` or `y///`)? There is an overview about half-way down the [Quote-Like Operators section of the perldocs](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators).

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56432775/edit) to include more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $substring = 'CAG';
my $str = 'CAGCAGCAGCAGPGHSMCAGCAG';
# look for a series of consecutive $substring not followed later by a longer such series
my ($longest_substring) = $str =~ /((?:\Q$substring\E)+)(?!.*?\1\Q$substring\E)/s;
my $repetitions = length($longest_substring // '') / length($substring);
```

Comment: Clever, and appears to be what the OP is asking about.  Would you be willing to expand your explanation a bit?  For example, why the `.*?`?  In my test, it seems to work without that.  **Edit** Also, if I add a bunch of CAGs on the end, it seems to only take the first one.  I think the `my ($longest_substring)` actually needs to capture all the matches and pick the longest.

Comment: @cxw the `.*?` is necessary (or at least the `.*` part of it, the `?` just maybe makes it faster) for e.g. "CAGHCAGCAG"; without it it would match the first "CAG"

Comment: Yep, it was the `.*?`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The matching operator with the `/g` modifier in list context returns all the matches. To count them, we can impose scalar context to the result:

```
my @matches = $str =~ /$substring/g;
my $count = scalar @matches;
```

which returns 6.

It can be further shortened to

```
my $count = () = $str =~ /$substring/g;
```

Where the `() =` assignment forces list context, but assigning it to a scalar variable forces the scalar context.

Note that this doesn't report the correct number if the matches are overlapping, e.g.

```
my $str = 'CACACAC';
my $substring = 'CAC';
```

The above expression would return 2, because matching with `/g` starts searching for the next match where the last match ended. To fix that, use the look-ahead assertion which doesn't consume the matching part:

```
my $count = () = $str =~ /(?=$substring)/g;
```

Comment: Thanks may be you didn't understand what i want is the string "CAGCAGCAGCAGPGHSMCAGCAG" return 4 because the max repeated sequence of CAG is 4

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my $number = () = $str =~ /$substring/gi;
print $number;
```